# discord.py embed field interval is so short

Tags: python, discord.py

When using Embed in discord.py, the spacing between fields is too narrow.
What should I do to widen that gap?

```
embed = discord.Embed(title="test", description="test")
embed.add_field(name="player1", value="ccc", inline=True)
embed.add_field(name="player2", value="bbb", inline=True)
embed.add_field(name="player3", value="aaa", inline=True)

await self.__interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```

[image]

I hope it comes out like the picture below.

[image]

Comment: To achieve smth like the image below you could add the fields for the first player (player1, name, level) with `inline=True` then for the 2nd player the field with name "player2" would have `inline=False` but the other fields like name and level would use `inline=True` and so on for every other player.

Comment: I'm not sure if @boez suggestion works. If I'm not mistaken, the field that is defined with `inline=False` will not allow the next fields defined with `inline=True` to be inline with it.

Comment: One idea I thought of for this to work would be to add invisible characters at the end of field values, just for tabulation purposes.

Comment: @Hazzu you're right i tested this on a online embed creator and set every `inline` to `True`, see the outlook [here](https://embed.dan.onl/?id=tHACyUu)

Comment: @Hazzu That's good idea! Can you tell me how do I add invisible characters?

Answer (score 0):

One idea to make this work as desired is to force the embed to be wider. You can do this by adding more text to the description. If you really don't have any more information to add the description, you can enter invisible characters:

```py
INVISIBLE_CHAR = "‎ "

# adjust the number of invisible characters to get the desired width
# i'm using 150 here just for a test
description = "test" + 150 * INVISIBLE_CHAR


embed = discord.Embed(title="test", description=description)
embed.add_field(name="player1", value="ccc", inline=True)
embed.add_field(name="player2", value="bbb", inline=True)
embed.add_field(name="player3", value="aaa", inline=True)

await self.__interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```